# Change time.Time timezone without reparsing

Tags: parsing, go, time, timezone

I am dealing with time.Time objects that has been parsed with the wrong timezone. They internally have a UTC tz but the original data come from a legacy MySQL database that internally store datetimes with the timezone Europe/Paris.

I would like to change the internal timezone of the time without reparsing it. I have tried the time.In() function but it does not solve my use case because it return the same time for another timezone.

My ultimate solution would be to use https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation to recreate the date from the value of the original with the proper location. However if this could be avoided this would be better.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Comment: What TZ do you want it to be associated with in the end? UTC or local?

Comment: @peterSO Question is clear and doesn't require any code to me. If you disagree, you can downvote.

Comment: What is the exact format in your database? Is there a TZ explicitly associated with it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just `Add` a fixed offest to them?

```
t,_ := time.Parse(...)
t = t.Add(-4 * time.Hour) // or whatever offset makes it work

// t is now correct utc time
// In should work less badly:
localTime := t.In(myRealLocation)
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good lead. Any thoughts about DST with this ? I guess there is no way to know about it since the MySQL datetime type does not store any tz/offset.

Comment: Ug. Time is the worst. You really have local timestamps that adjust to DST without notating anything about their timezone info? If so, I can't think of a way other than checking dates and adjusting the offset.

Comment: Storing timestamps without timezone information really should be a capital offense...

Comment: Storing anything other than utc at all is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, the mysql server is inserting dates based on its configured timezone which is Europe/Paris and sadly the datetime type does not carry any tz/offset. Anyway I'm goind to mark yhis as accepted since it fit my request. I didn't though about that in the first place.
@Kaedys I agree, but this is a very old legacy DB for which I have little control.